# Discord.py error syntaxerror: invalid syntax

Tags: async-await, discord.py

I’m coding a discord bot. I have a problem at the line 58. I don’t know what I need to do. I’m using repl.it to code my bot and Uptime robot to make my bot always online. My bot is in French, so don’t take care of the weird orthography. This is my code:.

**main.py**

```py
#imports
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from keep_alive import keep_alive

import discord
import os
import time
import random
import json
import choice
import youtube_dl
import datetime
import time

#clients
client = commands.client(command_prefix='-', help_command=None)
client = discord.Client()

#events
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    activity = discord.Game(name="Amogus", type=1)
    print("Amogus est en ligne!")

#commandes
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Pong! le message à été envoyé avec **{0}** ms'.format(round(bot.latency, 2)))

@client.command()
async def imposter(ctx):
  await ctx.send(". 　　　。　　　　•\nﾟ　　。 　　.\n.　　　　　。　　 。　. \n.　　 。　　　　　 ඞ 。 . 　　 • 　　　　•\n  {message.author.mention} was An Impostor.　 。　.\n0 Impostor remains 　 　　。\n　　　.　　　. ,　　　　.　 .")

@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
  embed=discord.Embed(title="-help", description="Ici, vous pouvez voir les différentes commandes du bot! Si l'Usage contient [], ça veut dire que l'attribut n'est pas obligatoire. Si l'usage contient <>, ça veut dire que l'attribut est obligatoire", color=0xff0000)
  embed.add_field(name="-help", value="Envoie ce message.\nUsage: -help [nom de la commande].", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="-sus", value="Vérifie votre chance.\nUsage: -sus", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="-coinflip", value="Fait un pile ou face.\nUsage: -coinflip", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="-ping", value="Envoie le ping du bot.\nUsage: -ping\n", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="-cheh", value="Envoie cheh avec un GIF.\nUsage: -cheh\n", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="-dice", value="Lance des dés\nUsage: -dice <nombre de dés> <nombre de faces>\n", inline=False)
  embed.set_footer(text="\nFaites -help [le nom de la commande] pour obtenir plus d’information sur une commande spécifique\n\nPar W1L7")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  
@client.command()
async def coinflip(ctx):
  coinflip = ['pile', 'face']
  await ctx.send(random.choice(coinflip))

@client.command()
async def cf(ctx):
  coinflip = ['pile', 'face']
  await ctx.send(random.choice(coinflip)

@client.command()
async def maps(ctx):
  maps-au = ['https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/among-us-wiki/images/3/35/The_Skeld_map.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/310?cb=20201111005126', 'https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/among-us-wiki/images/7/77/MIRA_HQ_map.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/310?cb=20201111004730', 'https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/among-us-wiki/images/a/ab/Polus_map.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/310?cb=20201111010008', 'https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/among-us-wiki/images/a/a1/The_Airship_map.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/310?cb=20210419084345']
  await ctx.send(random.choice(maps-au))

@client.command()
async def cheh(ctx):
  await ctx.send("par le pouvoir du grand CHEHHHHHHHHHHHHH\nhttps://cdn.nerdschalk.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/tenor-26.gif")

@client.command(name='dice')
async def dice(ctx, number_of_dice: int, number_of_sides: int):
  dice = [
    str(random.choice(range(1, number_of_sides + 1)))
    for _ in range(number_of_dice)
  ]
  await ctx.send(', '.join(dice))
  
@client.command()
async def sus(ctx):
  chance = ['sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus','sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus','sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus','sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus','sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus','sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus','sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus','sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus','sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'sus', 'when the imposter is sus\nhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bZ0hkiIKt0']
  await ctx.send(random.choice(chance))

#mise en ligne
keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

**.env**

```
TOKEN=<I paste my token here>
```

Everything seems ok, but in the console, it is write this:
or
**console**

```
File main.py, line 58:
async def maps(ctx):
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@client.command()
async def cf(ctx):
  coinflip = ['pile', 'face']
  await ctx.send(random.choice(coinflip)
```

Make sure to double-check your brackets.

```
client = commands.client(command_prefix='-', help_command=None)
client = discord.Client()
```

You are overwriting the variable here and the discord.Client() is not needed.

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')
client.remove_command('help')
```

It Will work since commands.client doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @W1L7 if I have solved your issue, please mark it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).